# Node Js writeFile always return 0 bytes when looping through many Base64 data

Tags: node.js

I have about more than 7.000 Base64 data that I want to save into a file using NodeJs, I can do this just fine when looping only up to 100 data or a little more, but if I try to loop all data at the same time it always makes 0-byte files.

here is my code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < result.recordset.length; ++i) {
                              
            var NewGambar = result.recordset[i].CustomerID + "_" + result.recordset[i].CustomerCode; 
            var extention = ".jpg";
            var dir = "image/customer/";
            
            var isBase64 = require('is-base64'); 
         
            if(result.recordset[i].Blob != null) {
                var base64Data = Buffer.from(result.recordset[i].Blob).toString('base64'); 
                
                if (isBase64(base64Data, { allowEmpty: false })) {
                    require("fs").writeFile("../" + dir + NewGambar + extention, base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
                      if (err) console.log(err);
                    }); 
                    
                    console.log(dir + NewGambar + extention);
                } 
                
            } 
    }
```

The above code is working properly when I change `result.recordset.length` into a small number like 10 or 100, but when I put 1000 or more it will always write 0 byte files.

Comment: I guess because of synchronous. Before `writeFile()` success, index `i` is moved. Can you check `writeFileSync` function instead of `writeFile`?

Comment: @Zem dang, I don't know it was THAT simple, thanks. it works properly if I'm using writeFileSync